# C++ how to make simple sha256 generator with boost?

Tags: c++, math, boost, encryption, sha256

I need a simple string to sha256 generator class. I do not want to build big libraries for that like openSSL or Cripto++ - all I want is to turn strings into sha256. How to create such class or where to get it?

Comment: Which side channel attacks are relevant?

Comment: Usually it is a bad idea to try to implement complex cryptography by yourself if you do not have extensive experience with the math involved.

Comment: Why is "boost" relevant? Have you looked up the algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like others have said, I was under the impression that hashing under SHA256 is not trivial enough to simply implement yourself as a subset of a bigger coding project. If you take a look at the [wikipedia page for SHA-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2), you will notice some pretty intense math. If you would like the actual encryption abstract (the math theory itself), it can be found [here](http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/description;jsessionid=17AE4F01F8F740270901CAA26097783A.espacenet_levelx_prod_5?CC=US&NR=2002122554A1&KC=A1&FT=D&date=20020905&DB=&locale=en_EP). If you're like most programmers whose emphasis is not in security, then you will probably want to simply use someone else's tested and tried implementation. You can find a good few [here](http://www.aarongifford.com/computers/sha.html). Let me know if this helped. Sorry I couldn't answer your question with straight code or something of that nature.

Answer (score 2):

You find C source code directly in the section 8 of [RFC 6234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6234). Make sure you check the [errata](http://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=4634) also.

Answer (score 1):

you want this?

```
static void
sha2_round(const unsigned char *data, sph_u32 r[8])
{
    int i;
    sph_u32 a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h;
    sph_u32 w[64];

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i ++)
        w[i] = sph_dec32be_aligned(data + (4 * i));
    for (i = 16; i < 64; i ++) {
        w[i] = SPH_T32(SSG2_1(w[i - 2]) + w[i - 7]
            + SSG2_0(w[i - 15]) + w[i - 16]);
```

go to http://www.saphir2.com/sphlib/
and download it.  it's under the GPL.  look in sha2.c

beware, it doesn't have a lot of documentation.  it's set up for people who already know what they're doing.

Answer (score 0):

GNU coreutils has a very simple source code.
just download coreutils, they even have a test suite you can build, and the source code is full of comments and docs.